# How to prove this upper bound of generalized Mangoldt function?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, arithmetic-functions

Define $\Lambda_k(n,x)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu(d)\left(\ln\frac xd\right)^k$, where $n$ is a positive integer and $x$ is a positive real number.

Let $n=p_1^{a_1}...p_r^{a_r}$, prove that $\Lambda_k(n,x)\leq r!\binom kr(\ln x)^{k-r}(\ln p_1)...(\ln p_r)$.

Remark. It's Eq(1.49) of Analytic Number Theory of Iwaniec.

Comment: Have you tried following the steps given below the exercise? The book basically tells you how to prove this (note there is a typo above equation (1.48); it should read $\Lambda_j \leq L^{k-j} \Lambda_k$.

Comment: Sorry, should read $\Lambda_j \leq L^{j-k} \Lambda_k$.

Comment: I have proved other Eqs except (1.49) which I tried mathematical induction but failed. It seems that we can directly get (1.49) via definition but I don't know how to derive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comment, I'll assume your comfortable with the following multiplication formula
$$
\tag{1}
\Lambda_k(mn,x) = \sum_{0\leq j\leq k} \binom{k}{j} \Lambda_j(n) \Lambda_{k-j}\left(m,\frac{x}{n}\right), \qquad (m,n)=1.
$$
We wish to show that if $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$, then
$$
\tag{2}
\Lambda_k(n,x) \leq r! \binom{k}{r}(\log x)^{k-r} (\log p_1)\cdots(\log p_r).
$$
If $n=p^a$ (so $r=1$), we can just compute this directly:
$$
\Lambda_k(p^a,x) = (\log x)^k - \left(\log\frac{x}{p}\right)^k = (\log x)^k \left(1-\left(1-\frac{\log p}{\log x}\right)^k\right) \leq (\log x)^k \left(\frac{k\log p}{\log x} \right)
$$
upon using the inequality
$$
1-(1-t)^k \leq k t\quad \text{for $t\in[0,1]$}.
$$
Thus we have (2) when $r=1$.

For the induction step, write $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_{r-1}^{a_{r-1}}$ with $p_1<\cdots<p_{r-1}$ and $r\leq k$ and suppose that suppose that (2) holds for integers with $r-1$ prime factors. Let $p_r$ be a prime with $p_r>p_{r-1}$. Then since $\Lambda_k(p_r^a) = (\log p_r)^k (a^k-(a-1)^k)$, we have by (1) and the induction hypothesis that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Lambda_k(p_r^a n,x) &= \sum_{j=0}^{k-r+1} \binom{k}{j} \Lambda_j(p_r^a) \Lambda_{k-j}\left(n,\frac{x}{p_r^a}\right) \\
&\leq \sum_{j=0}^{k-r+1} \binom{k}{j} \left[ (\log p_r)^j (a^j-(a-1)^j) \right]\\
&\qquad\qquad \times  \left[(r-1)! \binom{k-j}{r-1} \left(\log \frac{x}{p_r^a}\right)^{k-j-(r-1)} (\log p_1)\cdots (\log p_{r-1}) \right]\\
&= (r-1)!(\log p_1)\cdots (\log p_r) \\
&\qquad\qquad\times\sum_{j=0}^{k-r+1} \binom{k}{j}\binom{k-j}{r-1} (a^j-(a-1)^j) (\log p_r)^{j-1}\left(\log \frac{x}{p_r^a}\right)^{k-j-(r-1)}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Since (see derivation below)
$$
\binom{k}{j}\binom{k-j}{r-1} = \frac{r}{j}\binom{k}{r}\binom{k-r}{j-1} ,
$$
and the summand above is $0$ when $j=0$, the last line above is
$$
r! \binom{k}{r} (\log p_1)\cdots (\log p_r) \sum_{j=1}^{k-r+1} \frac{1}{j}\binom{k-r}{j-1} (a^j-(a-1)^j)(\log p_r)^{j-1} \left(\log \frac{x}{p_r^a}\right)^{k-r-(j-1)}.
$$
The sum over $j$ is less than or equal to
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j=1}^{k-r+1} \binom{k-r}{j-1} a^{j-1} (\log p_r)^{j-1}\left(\log \frac{x}{p_r^a}\right)^{k-r-(j-1)} &= \sum_{j=0}^{k-r} \binom{k-r}{j} (\log p_r^a)^j \left(\log \frac{x}{p_r^a}\right)^{k-r-j} \\
&= \left(\log \frac{x}{p_r^a}+\log p_r^a\right)^{k-r} \\
&= (\log x)^{k-r}.
\end{aligned}
$$
**Derivation of binomial identity:**

$$
\begin{aligned}
\binom{k}{j}\binom{k-j}{r-1} &= \frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!} \cdot \frac{(k-j)!}{(r-1)!(k-j-(r-1))!} \\
&= r \frac{k!}{r!(k-r)!} \cdot\frac{(k-r)!}{j!(k-j-(r-1))!}\\
&=\frac{r}{j} \frac{k!}{r!(k-r)!} \cdot\frac{(k-r)!}{(j-1)!(k-r-(j-1))!}\\
&=\frac{r}{j} \binom{k}{r}\binom{k-r}{j-1}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I have read your proof and I still have some questions: Is it that $\Lambda_k(p_r^a)$ should be $(\log p_r)^k (a^k-(a-1)^k)$; $\binom{k}{j}\binom{k-j}{r-1}$ should be $\frac r{k-r+1} \binom{k}{r}\binom{k-r+1}{j}$

Comment: @QWQ I've edited my answer. There were actually several typos that I have corrected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice proof :)